# The problem of simple cloth objects penetrating each other

Tags: animation, objects, cloth-simulation, collision, force-fields

There are multiple cloth objects which are raised by two different force fields. Both cloth objects are physics-based, and the object collision of those cloth is 0.02m.

I have a problem with them penetrating each other. Where is the cause of this failure? (I'm trying to make paper with these model.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update 1** (failed)
-Changed Quality Steps from 5 to 80.
-Changed Distance of Object Collisions from 0.02m to 0.03m.
[image]

**Update 2**(gets better) 
-Added Collision to all cloth objects. Changed the order of layer in Modifier Properties.
-Changed Distance of Object Collisions from 0.03m to 0.05m.
[image]
[image]

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: increasing the quality steps can often solve it

Comment: thanks for your advice. I increased Quality Steps extremely to 80, but the cloth objects are still penetrating :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collision should be enabled as well:

[image]

I see, you have enabled object collision, but where is no object with collision in the scene

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I've added Collision to all my cloth objects. Seems it stars working after I changed the order of the Collision layer in Modifier Properties. (pls refer the added screen-shot.) 
Movement isn't perfect still, but, it seems the clothe objects are trying to avoid each other as you can see in the new screen shot that I've added.

Comment: Then you set up like this, it is to difficult for blender to calculate intersections, because distance between points to big. Why don't you set subdivision at the beginning?

Comment: I once read an article where someone wrote that if you don't set the Subdivision after the Cloth , the Cloth will move strangely. But when I imagine how the calculation itself will be done, it seems you are right. I will set the subdivision first. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: My problem has suddenly been solved. Sorry for asking a similar question twice, but if there are any Blender beginners who faced the same problem [here's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/241076/the-problem-of-cloth-objects-penetrating-each-other) my solution.