# The problem of cloth objects penetrating each other

Tags: objects, cloth-simulation, collision

I've been having this problem for a while. I've asked about the same problem here before, and I've taken your advice into account, but it hasn't solved the problem. I have tried to adjust the model to make it simpler. Can anyone tell me why? I am a beginner and would be  grateful if you could give me any help to understand how this problem occurs.

**What's there:**
Here we have two cloth objects (Object 1) that soar by  wind force field.
They both have the same Collision setting and Cloth physics setting.
On the other hand, there's a flat object (Object 2). Which is added only collision setting.

**Problem:**
When the simulation is played, two "Object 1" soars and approaches "Object 2."  Two "Object 1" avoid "Object 2" when they fly, but two "Object 1" penetrate each other when they come into contact.

**I've already tried (but the problem was not solved):**

- Added Solidify setting to "Object 1."
- Enabled self collision setting.
- Raised Quality steps of the cloth to a maximum of 80.
- Raised Quality steps of collision to 20.

Please see the screenshot images below for a detailed description of each object and what it looks like in a collision.
("Object 2" is currently based on the leather preset in order to reproduce paper).


[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was able to solve this problem about an hour after I posted my question!!! :)
The answer to [this past question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68799/how-to-make-2-cloths-collide-with-each-other/68817#68817) helped me a lot. So thanks you. 
 
All I had to do was select all the "Object 2" objects that existed as separate objects, merge them with "Ctrl+J", add Collision and Cloth again, and enable Self Collision in the Cloth settings. It was a very simple solution and I am very happy with the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need *Self Collision* when the plane doesn't touch itself. Just **uncheck *Single Sided* in the *Collision* settings** so the collision detection works on both sides. Then you don't need the *Solidify* modifier for the collision detection but just for thickness.

Use default settings for the cloth physics.

**Example**

Here the topmost plane has a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to make it less stiff and more cloth-like and a *Solidify* modifier just to give it some thickness. Self Collision is enabled because it folds when it falls down. It also uses the *Leather* preset, so it has more mass => less air friction => falls faster.

The other two planes are duplicates but have only a *Cloth* and a *Collision* modifier and no Self Collision.

[image: example animation]
<sup>Good settings</sup>

Here are the settings, wireframe & face orientation overlay enabled:

[image: settings]

As you can see the plane 2 is upside down (red face orientation). This happens when you have [X] *Single Sided* active in the *Collision* settings:

[image: animation with bad settings]
<sup>Bad settings</sup>

Comment: Thanks to your more detailed explanation of how it works, I now understand the intent of the advices that I have received from others in the past. The reference animations are also excellent and helped me a lot. Thanks again!